# Is SQL becoming obsolete?

Tags: sql, orm, doctrine

Interested in some opinions on whether SQL is becoming obsolete. At my place of work, ORMs (in particular, Doctrine) are growing more popular for our web dev projects, and early indications seem to be suggesting that it's capable of doing pretty much everything we need for these small to medium sized apps (haven't yet had any major reporting requirements though). Is this the future of data modelling for web dev projects? (Apologies in advance if this is not the forum for this type of question).

Comment: ORMs generate SQL for you. And you still need SQL for the special cases when you need to optimize a piece of code.

Comment: You're lucky, then.  I've never been able to use an ORM without writing SQL.  Maybe it's the ones I've used, though:  Hibernate and django.

Comment: Considering this is still relevant and on my mind today I find it a bit odd that this question is closed.  A Google search certainly isn't helpful on this topic.  Why **shouldn't** some Stack Exchange site have anything to say about this topic?  I guess I could just wait for a Coding Horror or Joel article but... really?

Answer (score 0):

SQL is not obsolete nor is it becoming so.  There are plenty of programmatic interfaces that make it less of a requirement to learn it in the early stages of application development, but nothing replaces good knowledge about it.

It is also interesting to note that several NoSQL backends support a subset of SQL as an interface to them.  It will be a long time before it goes away.

Comment: I don't agree. I think SQL is extremely obsolete these days. Queries are unproportionally complicated / unreadable comparing to needs. Simple tasks require much work. JOINs are ugly. Many to many relations, which are very common, require ugly queries. There are ORMs that are like workarounds, but they still produce that ugly SQL syntax and are not flexible enough. It's almost 30 years since it's official standard. Since then, IT world changed, projects are much more complicated, but SQL stays - more or less - the same. It's just old, clunky leftover.

Comment: I partially agree with you Robok,  relational databases, also known as RDBMSes, are not designed for the current amount of data and should be considered legacy technology. Column-oriented data bases are currently superior by far when it comes to reading the content. This model is being used by google and other big ones for various apps. A column-based DBMS engine that also uses compression can beat a RBMS engine by an average of 50-fold. CBDB being a current step, the next one is Volumetric DB, but it's not the current topic here.